# Removing last list element by popping

Tags: python, list

I have the following piece of Python code where I am trying to empty out list A by removing one element at a time starting from the end. I cannot seem to reduce the list to an empty one and I would like to know why not. Any insight would be extremely appreciated.

```
A = [3,4,5,6,2]
for i in A:
    A.pop()
```

Comment: Note that lists have a clear method: `A.clear()`.  If you're trying to consume the list like a job queue, then consider a while loop instead `while A: item = A.pop()`

Comment: Do not modify a list while iterating over it. Instead iterate over `range(len(A))` because the range will have a predefined size.

Comment: Why can't you just `clear` the list, or why not just do `A = []`? What is the problem you are tying to solve?

Comment: Yeah...That is the best way to clear a list. One possibility why the OP wants to do it like this might be that OP is trying to solve some challenge which asks the OP to clear a list just by using `pop()`. That is the only possibility that I can think of.

Comment: for the 3rd i in loop, A still has 3 items and pop the third one, then for the 4th i in loop, A already remains 2 items and have nothing act as 4th i so the loop stop. Append or delete list items when loop over often give unexpected result unless you are really clear what you are doing, so better avoid doing that.

Comment: If the only requirement is that `pop` is used, you could do: 1.`A = [A[0]]`
2.`A.pop()`
3.`print(A)`

Answer (score 1):

```
var = [3,4,5,6,2]
for x in range(len(var)):
    a = var.pop(-1)
    print(a)
```

or reverse a list

```
var = var[::-1]
```

Comment: As commented in another answer, why not just `while A:`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
A = [3,4,5,6,2]

for a in range(len(A)):
    A.pop(-1)
```

Output:

```
>>> A
[]
```

You can also use a `list comprehension` instead of a traditional `for` loop:

```
A = [3,4,5,6,2]
[A.pop(-1) for a in range(len(A))]
```

Output:

```
>>> A
[]
```

Comment: As asked in another answer, why not just `while A:`?

Comment: That is another way of doing it

Comment: Also, you don't need to specify `-1` since `pop` will drop the last element from the `list` regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are trying to iterate through the elements of a list while the length of the list is reduced by 1 for each iteration.

This is not the right way to do this,

Try this,

```
A = [3,4,5,6,2]
for _ in range(len(A)):
    A.pop()
```

This will work.

Note: Never loop through a list in which you are going to perform some operations inside the loop-body. Try duplicating the list or use some other conditions.

Comment: Why not just `while A:`?

Answer (score 0):

This issue you are facing because you are trying to iterate the loop from first element and trying to remove the last element of the list. at one pint for loop runs out of element in a list hence it stops and you don't get empty list.

The proper solution will be to reverse iterate through the list and remove the elements.

Sample Code :

```
A = [3,4,5,6,2]
for i in range( len(A) -1 , -1, -1):
        A.pop()
        print (A)
```

Comment: As asked in another answer, why not just `while A:`?

Comment: In my opinion if we use `while A:` the code will go in infinite loop. However if you have different implementation using `While` please do post the code so that we all can learn a new thing from it .